# Library dependencies in Go

Tags: go, dependencies

I've created a library/package in Go and the consensus was that only applications include a `vendor` folder in their project and libraries don't.

So now I included [my package](https://github.com/gerbenjacobs/docserv) in another (`govendor`'ed) project and everything worked fine, untill it got to Jenkins and it had to use its local resources, where 2 of the dependencies were missing.

My project readme says all you need to do is `go get` my project and you're done. But that's not the case in case you're using govendoring.

What should be the approach for my library? Can this be solved, or is this 'problem' just something the end-user has to solve because they use `govendor`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is more of an opinion question I guess, however I'll share what I use.

I use [git subtree](https://developer.atlassian.com/blog/2015/05/the-power-of-git-subtree/) for vendoring sub repos in my tree then add a `//go:generate` line to update it later on, for example:

```
➜ git subtree add --prefix vendor/xxx/yyy/zzz https://github.com/xxx/yyy/zzz master --squash
```

Then add `//go:generate git subtree pull --prefix vendor/xxx/yyy/zzz https://github.com/xxx/yyy/zzz master --squash` to one of my library files.

And just run `go generate` before I make release.

That solves the vendoring issue without the need of any external tools.

Live example: https://github.com/OneOfOne/xxhash/blob/master/xxhash_cgo.go

Comment: So that means the project maintainer needs to run go generate before pushing their latest changes?

Comment: @GerbenJacobs correct, but that also means it is the project maintainer's job to ensure the vendored libs are working as expected.

Comment: Alright, I see your point. This is all pretty different from other languages that have vendored libs. So I guess that really does make it a opinion question. I'll accept your answer anyway and see what approach I want to take. Thanks.